# Combining 2d numpy array "row-wise"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two 2d-arrays (but rows doesn't have same length) created with numpy:

```py
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [6,7,8,9]]

b = [[1,2,30,40,50],
     [6,7,80,90,100]]
```

I would like to combine this two arrays into a new array, keeping the repeated values and adding the new ones "row-wise":

```py
#desired output

c = [[1,2,3,4,5,30,40,50],
     [6,7,8,9,80,90,100]]
```

I tried many approaches, including `np.apply_along_axis` with `np.unique` or simply looping each row and appending to a list and then creating an array form that list. The closest result i got was an array of arrays, like so:

```
array(array([1,2,3,4,5,30,40,50]), array([6,7,80,90,100]))
```

The above result isn't helpful, i need a numpy array. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `a` has two elements, one with length 5 and one with length 4. Is it intentional?

Comment: Yes, they won't share the same dimensions.

Comment: is there any duplicate in each sub-array of `a` and `b` ?

Comment: Can't ensure that, since i will apply this a machine learning algorithm with any dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `union`:

```
[np.union1d(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Output:

```
[array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 30, 40, 50]),
 array([  6,   7,   8,   9,  80,  90, 100])]
```

If you really need list of lists:

```
[np.union1d(x,y).tolist() for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 30, 40, 50], [6, 7, 8, 9, 80, 90, 100]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do the job!